# Question about Evans's proof of of the mean value forlmula for harmonic functions in Partial Differential Equations

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I am trying to understand the proof of the mean value formula for Laplace's equation in Partial Differential Equations by Evans: If $u \space \epsilon \space C^2(U)$ is harmonic, then [image]

(16) is equivalent to $$ u(x) = \frac{1}{n\alpha(n) r^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B(x,r)} udS = \frac{1}{\alpha(n) r^{n}}\int_{B(x,r)} udS$$

Here, $\alpha(n)$ is the volume of the unit ball in  $ \Bbb{R}^n$.

He starts the proof with this line:
[image]

I am confused about the second equality in this statement.  I can see he is using the transformation $ y = x + rz$ but the Jacobian of this transformation should be $r^n$ and then that would get you $$\frac{1}{n\alpha(n) r^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B(x,r)} u(y)dS = \frac{1}{n\alpha(n) r^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B(x,r)} u(x+rz) r^ndS = \frac{r}{n\alpha(n)}\int_{\partial B(x,r)} u(x+rz)dS $$

According to the proof as laid out in the book, that final $r$ outside the integral should cancel out somehow but I'm not sure how. Can someone elaborate how that equality works out?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The Jacobian is $r^{n-1}$ not $r^n$. This is because the integral is with respect to $(n-1)$-dimension surface measure

Comment: Thanks @JackT, that makes more sense now.  I understand now that the nth variable is essentially determined by the first n-1 variables so it's in essence an n-1 variable function that is being integrated.  Thanks again for your explanation.